# how to create facebook milestone with picture using API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Is there any way to send facebook milestone with picture using API ? I have checked the following documentation and found nothing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#milestones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the API suuports only the parameters listed on that document, you can't upload milestones with images attached via the API

Comment: It is possible, take a look here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/milestone/photos

Comment: Yep it's been added in the 18 months since i posted my answer

Comment: well yea, but I have problems using it. According to that documentation, the picture has to be 'uploaded'. So my problem is how to attach a photo using the PHP SDK automatically, without uploading a photo.